# Remove/Hide CustomBadge

Tags: iphone, ios

Im displaying a badge using CustomBadge with this code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


[self fillBadges];

//********** Start Custom Badge ***************//
NSString *myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",allBadge];

if (allBadge >= 1) {
    NSLog(@"Add One");
    CustomBadge *customBadgeAll = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:myNewString];
    [customBadgeAll setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 90, customBadgeAll.frame.size.width, customBadgeAll.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:customBadgeAll];      
}
//********** End Custom Badge ***************//


[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

}

When allBadge count is less than 1, I don't want the badge to show. How do I remove or hide it from the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class-wide variable for your customBadgeAll:

in your .h:

```
CustomBadge *customBadgeAll;
```

then you can easily remove the badge again:

```
if (allBadge >= 1) {
  NSLog(@"Add One");
  CustomBadge *customBadgeAll = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:myNewString];
  [customBadgeAll setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 90, customBadgeAll.frame.size.width, customBadgeAll.frame.size.height)];
  [self.view addSubview:customBadgeAll];      
}
else{
  [customBadgeAll removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Another way would be to set a the tag value of `customBadgeAll` to a special value and later retrieving it using `[self.view viewWithTag:...]`.

Hope this helps

Comment: The Tag option worked great. Thanks for the very fast response

Comment: Can we take this a step further?

Comment: Just press the checkmark that is displayed at the left side of this answer.

Comment: In comments: put ` around your code.
In answers/questions: intend your code by four spaces. Click the question mark at the right above the text box. All formatting possibilities will be displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the following code `customBadgeAll.hidden = YES` for hiding it ?